# TightVNC in Ubuntu 22.04 Hyper-V VM crashes when closing windows?

Tags: vnc, hyper-v

I'm having an issue which is driving me nuts. I've been trying to move over to Ubuntu 22 (from 18 right now) but can't get a stable VNC environment.

I installed 22.04 LTS it via Hyper-V Quick Create.

I installed xfce4 and tightvncserver.

My .vnc/xstartup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Session fail after a random amount of time (sometimes hours, sometimes less, like below). When it runs "normally," certain other things (most notably LibreOffice) will crash the VNC server when doing something as simple as closing a document.

Whenever it happens, the VNC client errors with "Failed to recv data from remote socket."

The Xtightvnc process is gone.

I see this in /var/log/kern.log:

```
Mar  2 12:23:37 mars kernel: [ 1281.469703] xiccd[4832]: segfault at e4 ip 000055ede2bd84f6 sp 00007ffc2ece1300 error 4 in xiccd[55ede2bd4000+5000] likely on CPU 3 (core 1, socket 0)
Mar  2 12:26:43 mars kernel: [ 1467.206087] Xtightvnc[4681]: segfault at 7fff82e42d08 ip 000055f205d65a76 sp 00007fff82e41d10 error 6 in Xtightvnc[55f205c34000+137000] likely on CPU 2 (core 1, socket 0)
```

The ip/sp pointers are different every time I've compared.

What's really curious is, despite MONTHS of searching, I'm not finding anyone else reporting similar issues. Surely I can't be alone. :)

I've used this arrangement / configuration since probably Ubuntu 16 (maybe earlier) without issue, but can't get past this in 22.04. I've given the VM 6 vCPUs and 8GB of memory. They hypervisor has an 8th Gen Core i7 with 6 CPUs/12 threads and 48GB of memory.

Any suggestions would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: Here are some suggestions: 1. Switch back to X11 from Wayland. 2. Use Remmina instead of VNC. 3. Use WSLg instead of HyperV+VNC